# Is there any configuration on WindowMaker to hide the mouse cursor after some seconds?

Tags: window-manager

Is there any configuration on WindowMaker to hide the mouse cursor after some seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking and in what context - some more info would be welcome.

Maybe the following thread is related : [Hide mouse cursor/change cursor location?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/hide-mouse-cursor-change-cursor-location-435939/)

> I have spent hours for finding a
>   solution to hide a cursor in
>   kiosk-purpose CentOS 5.5 +
>   WindowMaker-0.92. Finally I found it
>   so I like to share:
>
> 1. install unclutter from EPEL repository (unclutter-8-2.el5.i386 in
>      my case)
> 2. edit ~/GNUstep/Library/WindowMaker/autostart
>      and add
>
>    unclutter -display :0 -root -idle 1 &
>
> (without specifying -root, cursor
>   hides only in programs, not in window
>   manager, -idle xx means number of
>   seconds of mouse inactivity before
>   cursor hides)

Comment: It's just that! I'll try it when I back to work (in 3 days), but looks like it's a solution. More details? I'm using WMaker in a embeded system, and I would like my mouse cursor to hide after a few seconds, it's just that..